# Roots of unity, where $\omega^3 = 1, \omega \neq 1$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Say that $\omega^3 = 1$ and $\omega \neq 1$. Find the value of $(1 - \omega + \omega^2)(1 + \omega - \omega^2)$.

I'm not very good at the roots of unity. May I have a couple of hints to get started?

Comment: To get started, just expand like a polynomial multiplication problem, treating $\omega$ like a variable $x$. Then, everywhere you see $\omega^3$, put a $1$. Everywhere you see an $\omega^4$, note that $\omega^4 = \omega^3 \cdot \omega$. There is one more thing you may need to do: do you know anything about $1 + \omega + \omega^2$ from your class?

Comment: @hunter: Expanding like a polynomial, (I'm substituting x for $\omega$), $-x^4+2x^3-x^2+1$. This simplifies to...$x+2-x^2+1 = -x^2+x+3$.

Comment: @MathisLife I think you missed a negative.  $-\omega^4=-\omega$.

Comment: This may or may not be helpful
$$\begin{align}
\omega^2-1&=(\omega-1)(\omega+1)\\
\omega^3-1&=\dots\\
\omega^4-1&=(\omega-1)(\omega^3+\omega^2+\omega+1)\\
\omega^5-1&=(\omega-1)(\omega^4+\omega^3+\omega^2+\omega+1)\\
\omega^6-1&=(\omega-1)(\omega^5+\omega^4+\omega^3+\omega^2+\omega+1)\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the roots of the polynomial equation $x^3-1=0$ are $1, \omega, \omega^2$ (for the last note that $(\omega^2)^3=\omega^6=1^2=1$), and the sum of the roots is zero (see the coefficient of $x^2$ in the polynomial), you can save yourself a whole lot of work, if you are alert, by evaluating the expression as $$-2\omega\cdot-2\omega^2$$

I'll leave you to work out the detail, since you wanted a hint.

Motto: if you can, simplify before you multiply - but you have to learn to be alert.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1) Use $(A-B)(A+B)= …$

2) All you have to know is $\omega^k=\omega^{k\bmod 3}$ and $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$.

You should finally find the expression is equal to $4$.